# select list - content outputs key instead of label

Tags: 7

Drupal 7 v. 7.34 - content type. In my content type I use at least 3 fields with select lists. In each case the key is output instead of the label. I would expect the label to be displayed to the user.
E.g. the field 'theme' has the following available options:

wedding|wedding first dance
dancepromo|let's dance

The content shows 'wedding' instead of 'wedding first dance' and 'dancepromo' instead of 'let's dance'.

What am I doing wrong ?
Should I change the key|label order to label|key ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the display settings for your content type, and look at the display formatter for the field. it should be set to `Default`. The other option is Key.

[image]